# Match 2 values across 2 data sets to return third value?

Tags: excel, vlookup, distinct-values

The title isn't very descriptive, but here's a simple explanation of what I have:

Column A: List of fruits (Data set 1)

Column B: List of vegetables (Data set 1)

Column C: A counter for each fruit/vegetable combination of Data set 1 (numbers)

Column E: List of fruits (Data set 2)

Column F: List of Vegetables (Data set 2)

Column G: A counter for each fruit/vegetable combination of Data set 2 (numbers)

Suppose for data set 1, the fruit/vegetable combination of strawberry/carrot (columns A & B respectively) has a counter of 5 (column C) whereas for data set 2, the same fruit/vegetable combination of strawberry/carrot (columns E & F respectively) has a counter of 7 (column G).

Is there an excel formula that searches up each value in Column A/B to Column E/F and returns the respective value in column G? I know that vlookup looks for one specific cell in an array, but I don't think I can look up a unique combination across multiple columns.

Comment: so which number would be returned, the `5` or the `7` or a sum `12` or a concatenation `5,7`?

Comment: A concatenation preferably (5,7 as you mentioned).

Comment: are the combination unique per data set? `strawberry/carrot` can happen only once per dataset?

Comment: Strawberry/carrot happens can appear in either Data Set 1, Data Set 2, or both. There can be a combination of cherry/carrot or strawberry/broccoli in both data sets but there isn't a duplicate combination within the same data set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two concatenated SUMIFS:

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,"strawberry",B:B,"carrot") & "," & SUMIFS(G:G,E:E,"strawberry",F:F,"carrot")
```